# Access containing element of <script>

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've seen a few topics that hint along the lines I'm looking for, but I need to take this a step further.

I have a site that uses AJAX to insert new content as it is added to the site.  This content sometimes includes inline JavaScript.  As it is right now, if this inline JavaScript includes a `document.write()` call, the rest of the page content is wiped out and replaced with the contents of the write call and ruins the page.

These inline `<script>` elements are always contained within a `DIV`, but due to the nature of the site's software, the `DIV`s may appear more than once in the same post, and as such can't make use of names or IDs to help the script find where the new content goes.

I see that many posts say that the currently executing `<script>` should appear as the last element in `document.scripts`, however, what happens when the `<script>` is added mid-page via AJAX?  In the layout of the page, the `<script>` is not always the last one on the page, so if it is added after the page is finished loading, even if not at the end of the document, will it still appear as the last entry in `document.scripts`?

Comment: If you fetch the ajax content as a string rather than (I presume) letting a framework inject it into a page, you can do whatever you like with it?

Comment: What Alex K. said - fetch & store the script content, manipulate it to replace document.write calls or other problematic code, and then insert the corrected version into the DOM. No need to worry about the order of `document.scripts` if you fix things before putting it on the page.

Comment: My trouble is that this is a discussion forum, so I have no direct way to change the AJAX call. All I can do is decide the code that gets injected by the AJAX call.  What I'm doing is probably better served by a server side script like PHP, but I don't have access to the server either, so it has to be generated by JavaScript or some other in-line method.  The result will be a DIV with a SCRIPT inside that dynamically generates content and inserts it into the DIV, but because it's dynamic content, the DIV can't have a specific ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this answer only really satisfies my specific issue, it may be of assistance to others, so I'll post what I did:

I used some of the raw data that made up the javascript calls to create an ID for the containing DIV, allowing that DIV to have a unique ID that the script could access in the DOM.  This way, when the code was injected via the AJAX script and the inline script was executed, it would target its own container's innerHTML and overwrite itself with the intended code that was supposed to display on the page.

In my specific usage, my script would take a series of numbers as parameters and replace them with various images, symbols and words, depending on what the numbers represented.  I ended up formatting the output as something like:

```
<div id="{param1param2param3}">
<script>
   document.getElementById('param1param2param3').innerHTML={all the content the script is supposed to generate};
</script>
</div>
```

The result is the same whether the page is loaded normally or via AJAX.  In the rare case that there are two blocks with the same ID (meaning the exact same parameters), all browsers seem to handle it correctly and replace each DIV with the intended code.  I don't know if each script is actually targetting its own container or any of the others with the same ID, but since they'd all end up with identical contents anyway, it doesn't matter as long as all the DIVs get replaced with their intended content.
It could be further extended by having the script remove the ID from the DIV it was working on, so that other "identical" blocks don't try to execute on the same DIV over and over.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have a serious problem on your hands.

Once the document has finished rendering, `document.write` will replace it.  So if you are trying to include markup via AJAX that has such calls in SCRIPT elements and you want to execute those scripts, you're going to overwrite the document.

In other words, you really can't mix AJAX and `document.write`.  You need to rework to do without one or the other.